# SQL recursion with full hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, recursion

This is what my query looks like right now:

```
with allmembers (objectid, parentid, name, parentname, recursion) as 
(
-- anchor elements: where parentid = 25
select objectid, parentid, name, name as parentname, 0 as recursion
from orgs as orgs1 
where parentid = 25 

-- recursion begins here
union all 
select orgs2.objectid, orgs2.parentid, orgs2.name, orgs3.name as parentname, recursion + 1
from orgs as orgs2 
    join allmembers as orgs3 on orgs2.parentid = orgs3.objectid
)
-- we select all the results 
select *
from allmembers
```

It selects the orgs (organizations) from a list, where the parentid is 25 (these are the "root organizations") and joins them with all their child organizations, recursively, until there are none left. So we get a list of organizations and their parents.

My problem is that I get only the **direct** child/parents relationsships:

> ### name  |  parentname
>
> Sales | All_Employees
>
> Direct Sales | Sales

What is lost in this process is that "Direct Sales" is also a member of "All_Employees", **indirectly**, through "Sales". 
So I would rather have the following result added:

> ### name  |  parentname
>
> Sales | All_Employees
>
> Direct Sales | Sales
>
> **Direct Sales | All_Employees**

How to achieve this?

Comment: mysql or sql-server  ???

Comment: Microsoft SQl Server.

Comment: Show some example data.

Answer (score 0):

Without going too far and getting functions involved, would using a materialized path suffice for your needs?

```
create table orgs (objectid int, name varchar(128), parentid int);
insert into orgs values
 (26,'All Employees', 25)
,(27,'Sales', 26)
,(28,'Direct Sales',27);

with allmembers as (
-- anchor elements: where parentid = 25
  select 
      objectid
    , parentid
    , name
    , parentname = convert(varchar(128),'')
    , rootname   = name
    , recursion  = convert(int,0)
    , name_path  = convert(varchar(256),name)
  from orgs  
  where parentid = 25 
  -- recursion begins here
  union all 
  select 
      c.objectid
    , c.parentid
    , c.name
    , parentname = p.name
    , rootname   = p.rootname
    , recursion  = p.recursion + 1
    , name_path  = convert(varchar(256),p.name_path + ' > ' + c.name)
  from orgs as c 
      join allmembers as p on c.parentid = p.objectid
)
-- we select all the results 
select *
from allmembers
```

returns:

```
+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| objectid | parentid |     name      |  parentname   |   rootname    | recursion |              name_path               |
+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|       26 |       25 | All Employees |               | All Employees |         0 | All Employees                        |
|       27 |       26 | Sales         | All Employees | All Employees |         1 | All Employees > Sales                |
|       28 |       27 | Direct Sales  | Sales         | All Employees |         2 | All Employees > Sales > Direct Sales |
+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
```